# Proper use of .NET Concurrent Collections

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, concurrency

In my attempt to create concurrent `Socket` operations, I've created the following code:

```
ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> messageQueue;
ManualResetEvent resetEvent;
Thread outThread;   // -> new Thread(BeginSending);

public void BeginSending() // invoked by outThread
{
    while (true)
    {
        resetEvent.WaitOne();
        while (messageQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] msg;
            messageQueue.TryDequeue(out msg);
            // send msg via socket
        }
        resetEvent.Reset();
    }
}

public void QueueMessage(byte[] msg) // invoked by the main thread
{
    messageQueue.Enqueue(msg);
    resetEvent.Set();
}
```

Is adding items to the `ConcurrentQueue` while a different thread is iterating/dequeuing it a dangerous thing?

From my understanding many synchronized collections simply have individually synchronized methods, but is the same true for `concurrentQueue` and similar collections?
(`ConcurrentBag`, `ConcurrentDictionary`, `ConcurrentStack`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ConcurrentQueue` itself is OK, as long as you are not mutating the arrays stored as its elements.

However, your usage pattern with `ManualResetEvent` suggests that there is a better solution: if you use [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), you would be able to avoid doing manual synchronization.

Comment: The ManualResetEvent is inappropriate and will not work reliably.

Answer (score 2):

> Is adding items to the ConcurrentQueue while a different thread is iterating/dequeuing it a dangerous thing?

No, it is safe.

Answer (score 1):

The ConcurrentQueue is fine, the ManualResetEvent is not:

```
public void BeginSending() // invoked by outThread
{
    while (true)
    {
        resetEvent.WaitOne();
        while (messageQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] msg;
            messageQueue.TryDequeue(out msg);
            // send msg via socket
        }

    // context change
    messageQueue.Enqueue(msg);
    resetEvent.Set();
    // context change

        resetEvent.Reset();
    }
}
```

Such a sequence of events will result in an enqueued message being ignored.  Either use a BlockingCollection, as suggested by the other posters, or use a semaphore for signal/wait.

Comment: Hmm that is an interesting thought. How about simply adding a check before calling `WaitOne()`, something like: `if (messageQueue.Count == 0) resetEvent.WaitOne();`. Wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: @Acidic - maybe, for a single producer and single consumer yes, but why bother?  A BlockingCollection or using a Semaphore instead of a MRE will certainly work correctly for any number of producers/consumers.   A MRE does have its uses, but producer-consumer queues are not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The concurrent collections are designed to be thread safe. Using them saves you a lot of trouble by implementing them yourself.

Be aware though that the collection itself is synchronized, NOT the data inside it. Updating the objects inside the collections without attention for the other threads can bring race-conditions.

As with any usage of a class it helps if you have a understanding of the use and use-cases of the collections